# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Failed to fetch , REST with Node.js

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I try to make a Request using React Js and my Node.js REST api deployed on Heroku. And i am getting this Error `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Failed to fetch`. For some Reason i dont understand why this is so.

My code is looking like this

```
import './Home.css'
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Link , useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const MyLogin = () =>{
    const[username, setUsername] = useState('');
    const[password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const history = useHistory();

    function login(){
        let item = {username , password};
        fetch('https://instagramklone-restapi.herokuapp.com/api/login',{
            method : 'POST',
            mode : 'cors',
            headers:{
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(item)
        }).then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) =>{
            if(responseJson.message === 'OK'){
                localStorage.setItem('userinfo', username);
                history.push('/dashboard');
            }else{
                alert(responseJson);
            }
        });
    }

    return (
        <div align="center">
            <table width="61%" border="0">
            <div className="instagramlogo">
                <img src="images/43cc71bb1b43_2-removebg-preview.png"/>
            </div>
            <div className="login_page">
                <img border="0" align="center" src="images/images-removebg-preview.png" width="168" height="70" className="InstagramLogo" />
                <div className="usernameLogin">
                    <p align="center"><input type="text" name="T1" placeholder="  Phone number, username or email" size="33" onChange ={(e) =>setUsername(e.target.value)} className="inputBox" /></p>
                </div>
                <div className="usernameLogin">
                    <p align="center"><input type="password" name="T1" placeholder="  Password" size="33" onChange ={(e) =>setPassword(e.target.value)} className="inputBox" /></p>
                </div>
                <div className="usernameLogin">
                    <p align="center"><input onClick={login} type="submit" value="Login" name="B1" class="BtnLoginClass"/></p>
                </div>
                <div className="forgotPassword">
                    <p align="center"><Link to="#">Forgot Password?</Link><font face="Arial"/></p>
                </div>
            </div>
                <div className="No_account">
                <p align="center"><font face="Arial"/>No Account? <Link to="/register">Register!</Link></p>
                </div>
                <div className="get_app">
                    <p align="center"><font face="Arial"/> Get The app</p>
                </div>
                <div className="PlayStoreAppStoreArea">
                    <td width="204">
                    <p align="center">
                    &nbsp;<input type="image" src="images/appstore.png" width="169" height="51" align="right"/>
                    </p>
                    </td>
                    <td width="204">
                    <p align="center">
                    &nbsp;<input type="image" src="images/googlePlay.png" width="169" height="51" align="left"/>
                    </p>
                    </td>
                </div>
            </table>
        </div>
    );
};

export default MyLogin;
```

The Error is looking like this

[![9090.png]Error(https://i.postimg.cc/85h739mz/9090.png)](https://postimg.cc/yg863fGM)

Its supposed to authenticate as json and then sign in and navigate to the dashboard , but i am getting an error. Pls help.

**Edits**
I get this Error

```
Access to fetch at 'https://instagramklone-restapi.herokuapp.com/api/login' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Comment: Unhandled means you didn't handle the error, use catch() at the end of the request to see the error. This won't solve your problem but at least you can see the exact problem

Comment: @İlker, ok, i think it solved that, but gives a new Error , Please see edits.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it.

I had to add this to my Node.JS REST api

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    next();
 });
```

And it worked Like a charm, I also set the catch for the REST api and everything appears to be in good shape :)
Thanks everyone